# New Google Drive Ignores IconLink Property on File

Tags: google-drive-api

Ever since the new look for Google Drive has been in place, files uploaded by my company's app have been displaying the default file icon as opposed to the icon we are providing in our app.

This is how it looked in the old Drive:

[image: File icons work in old Drive]

And this is how it looks in the new Drive:

[image]

Nothing changed on our end. The only thing I did was open my Drive settings and switch back and forth between the new and old views of Drive.

After some brief research, I found out that the Google Drive SDK allows you to specify an `iconLink` property on files that get uploaded. I queried Drive and checked to make sure that the value was being set by our app, and it was.

My question is: why doesn't the new Google Drive seem to use the iconLink property? What do I need to do to make the new Google Drive view use the file icons I want instead of the default one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known limitation of the new Drive UI, and the team is working on implementing a fix. For the time being there is no way to workaround this issue. The iconLink field is read-only and so not a solution.

Comment: You mentioned the team is "working on implementing a fix". Is there an ETA for that?

Comment: No, unfortunately there is no ETA.

Comment: Three months later... any ETA?

Comment: This issue should now be fixed. I apologize for not updating folks sooner.

Comment: Is this really working now? Can you post the working solution as when I try to write the iconLink I get a 403 - "The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable."

Comment: I should clarify: the iconLink has always been read-only in the API. However, when defining your own file type for use in Drive, you can specify an icon to be used, and that will now show up correctly.